# 3 Way Switch Wiring Diagram

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have switch-switch-light fixture that stopped working (after I tried to replace with a digital wall timer switch, which ended not working) - changed all switches around with other existing ones in use and even the light fixture and still the light does not turn on - I do get power in the common black leading to light fixture (LF was working in a different location).

the first switch gets power from a piggy-back circuit line that enters the JB (there are 3 other lines feeding from this power circuit

My circuit is text book, but  the only thing I am doing differently is connecting wires at the side screw vs back orifice (initially all lines were set that way, but I swapped switches around from locations where they were working, with existing in this particular diagram - they still work at new locations, so does not seem to be faulty switches)

the second switch is actually powering on and off the LF, but the first LS is not powering off the second LS (light switch) when I flipped it to on or off position

could this be the problem? I don't have any other any ideas.

Thanks for the help
Phillip

[image]

Comment: The back stabs are connected to the screws.  The screws are the recommended prefer connection choice over the cheaper back stabs.  Which wire goes on which screw is what is important to know.  If that is mixed up, and you do not have pictures of before, it can be almost impossible to guess the right way.

Comment: Do you have a contact voltage tester/meter?

Comment: It seems to me that the switches may be connected in parallel and not in a 2way fashion.

Comment: Nothing appears wrong with your diagram. Is it possible there is a short between your travellers, or a short in the S1 box between line and a traveller? With power off at the breaker panel, can you check if there is continuity between the two travellers at S2?

Comment: If you can get power at the "hot" connection of the light fitting then, if the bulb is not faulty (and presumably you have tested for this), the problem of "no light" does not lie in the path  of the "hot" through the two switches. Instead, it must lie in the  path of the neutral conductor back to the junction box. Check any connections on the neutral (including light fitting, junction box, behind the switches).